# Roboframework - SeleniumLibrary - set specific user profile path for Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

my goal is to create a Roboframework script using SeleniumLibrary (or Selenium2Library), selecting a specific Profile Path for Chrome (I need to reuse profile).

This is the code I'm using:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Test Profile
    ${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    ${options.add_argument}=    Set Variable    --user-data-dir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.Test
    Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
    Go To    chrome://version  
    Wait Until Page Contains    JavaScript
    Capture Page Screenshot
```

If I run the script I don't receive any error, but unfortunately the chrome path is not effected by the desired setting (all the time is creating root+random path):
[image]

In the past I've successfully achieve this using Python code and Selenium Grid:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.Test') 
browser = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://192.168.99.100:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities())
```

Any help/comment is appreciated.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Test Profile
    ${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${options} add_argument --user-data-dir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.Test
    Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
    Go To    chrome://version  
    Wait Until Page Contains    JavaScript
    Capture Page Screenshot
```

If that doesn't work try without the `--`, i.e.

Try something like below

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Test Profile
    ${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${options} add_argument user-data-dir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.Test
    Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
    Go To    chrome://version  
    Wait Until Page Contains    JavaScript
    Capture Page Screenshot
```

Comment: Thx, got this error in both case: Calling method 'add_argument' failed: TypeError: add_argument() got an unexpected keyword argument '--user-data-dir' OR Calling method 'add_argument' failed: TypeError: add_argument() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user-data-dir'

Comment: That will have to do with some syntax of Robot framework, but the approach should be around this line itself. I will check i can find thd exact syntax

Comment: Thx Tarun, pls see my response, I made it work with different syntax

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with this syntax:

```
${chrome_options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys
    Call Method     ${chrome options}    add_argument    user-data-dir\=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.Test
    ${dc}   Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].DesiredCapabilities.CHROME  sys, selenium.webdriver
    ${Options}=    Call Method    ${ChromeOptions}    to_capabilities
    Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome_options}  desired_capabilities=${dc}
    Go To    chrome://version  
    Wait Until Page Contains    JavaScript
    Capture Page Screenshot
```